# Adding tor to the Thrift / Astyanax API

Tags: cassandra, thrift, astyanax

Im trying to add TOR on-top of thrift for Astyanax and im wondering if anyone has tried to or come accross any similar projects. Extensive googling (and even bing searching) has lead me nowhere. I stared looking through Astyanax's source code in an attempt to find where the actual connection between the client and Cassandra takes place and ended up at [this class](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/blob/master/src/main/java/com/netflix/astyanax/connectionpool/impl/ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl.java). As far as I can tell this plays some small part but what I really need to find is if the API uses a InputStream and OutputStream object to send and receive data and hopefully overload the connection.

This question might get closed as too localised, however im hoping that some Cassandra / astyanax gurus can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find where Cassandra builds the bridge between your client machine and the server. The class (or collection of classes) that provide the means of that connection will probably be using a socket which uses Input/Output streams to send and receive data.

Update:
Key classes to look into from the Thrift API (libthrift) which is used in Hector and Astyanax

- `org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket` - creates the socket that is used to connect to Cass.
- `org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport` - Handles the In/Out Stream and what data is  added to it (what u send/receive)

The next steps you should take are to divert the socket to connect to Cassandra through TOR rather than TCP/IP.